# Updating value in one row to another row based on same column value

Tags: sas

My dataset XXX comprises records where 2 rows form a pair based on same value of FRUIT column . The difference is that one row contains empty COUNTRY value field while second row contains actual COUNTRY value. Similarly that first row contains empty COLOUR field while second row contains actual COLOUR value. now I would like to populate the COLOUR value of  row (source) where COUNTRY value is populated, to the first row's empty COLOUR field (destination) where COUNTRY field is empty.

```
XXX DATASET [current]
FRUIT | COUNTRY | COLOUR
Banana | . | .
Banana | Spain | Yellow
Apple | . | .
Apple | USA | Red
Pear | China | Green
Pear | . | . 

YYY [DESIRED]
FRUIT | COUNTRY | COLOUR
Banana | . | Yellow
Banana | Spain | Yellow
Apple | . | Red
Apple | USA | Red
Pear | China | Green
Pear | . | Green
```

Of course this example is dumb, but it is valid business case.

Apologizes I could not attach code here as I am in a bus now frantically typing. I tried using first. and last. , But somehow the variable cannot be passed across rows.

Can you advise in this?

Comment: "I am in a bus" is not really valid excuse, sorry. Please try your best to deliver some example you tried so far.

Comment: Don't text and drive. Maybe ask a passenger to text for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing this, using `retain` to carry over values from previous rows. The trick is to retain a temporary column rather than the one you want to fill in:

```
data have;
input FRUIT $ COUNTRY $ COLOUR $;
infile cards dlm='|';
cards;
Banana | . | .
Banana | Spain | Yellow
Apple | . | .
Apple | USA | Red
Pear | China | Green
Pear | . | . 
;
run;

/*Sort missing values of COLOUR to the bottom within each FRUIT*/
proc sort data = have out = temp;
    by FRUIT descending COLOUR; 
run;

data want;
    set temp;
    by FRUIT;
    retain t_COLOUR 'placeholder';
    if first.FRUIT then do;
        t_COLOUR = .;
        if not(missing(COUNTRY)) then t_COLOUR = COLOUR;
    end;
    else COLOUR = coalescec(COLOUR, t_COLOUR);
    drop t_COLOUR;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
proc sort data=have;
by fruit country;
run;

data want( rename=(country1=country colour1=colour));
  set have end=eof;
     by fruit notsorted;
     if first.fruit then do;
       point = _N_ + 1;
       set have (keep= country colour rename= (country = country1 colour = colour1)) point=point;
    end;
   else do; 
       country1=country;
       colour1 = colour;
       end;
     drop country colour;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to apply the non-missing values of `COLOUR` to every record with the same value of `FRUIT`?  Sounds like a simple MERGE problem.

```
data YYY;
  merge XXX(drop=colour) XXX(keep=fruit colour where=(not missing(colour)));
  by fruit;
run;
```

Comment: Your method will drop the original  records with country and color values not missing.

Comment: @Mangowithice Why would it drop those variables? It is only dropping COLOUR, but then remerging it back on. Are there variables other than COLOUR that you want to move the values around?

Comment: Oh, I think I know what u mean ... Drop the column where we want it to be provided by the other row.